# Slick2D noClassDefFoundError for StateBasedGame

Tags: slick

I'm trying to write a 2D game using slick2D, and I thought I set everything up correctly, but I'm getting this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class javagame.Main_Game
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/newdawn/slick/state/StateBasedGame
```

My `Main_Game` class is the class with my main function and it extends `StateBasedGame`. I can't find this error or how to fix it when I try to search for it.

Comment: Are you attempting to execute your program from command line?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error, but I fixed it because when I imported the lwjgl.jar and slick.jar, I imported them into the "Modulepath". If its the same for you (assuming you're using eclipse), go to where you added your libraries (Properties>java Build Path>Libraries) and make sure you added you libraries to the "Classpath" rather than the "Modulepath".

Hope this helps.